# A llamar método C# en Selenium, el resultado me da un error de VS

Tags: c#

El método simplemente me tiene que dar un True o False, si está presente en elemento en el DOM. Al llamarlo se ejecuta bien, pero luego me da error de VS:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using SeleniumExtras;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;




namespace Selenium
{
    internal class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions(); // CREAMOS UNA INSTANCIA DEL NAVEGADOR 
            option.AddArguments("--windows-size=1920,1080"); // TAMAÑO CORRECTO PARA EL MODO headless   
            option.AddArguments("--disable-extensions"); // DESACTIVAR EXTENCIONES
            option.AddArguments("--user-agent/105.0.5195.127 CK={} (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko)");

            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(option); // CREAMOS EL OBJETO IWebDriver                                                                                      
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");


            string ruta = "/html/body/ul[4]/li[1]";
            
            var c = Presentado(ruta);
            Console.WriteLine(c);


        }
        /// METODO PRESENTADO POR Xpath /////
        public static bool Presentado(string ruta)
        
        { 
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            var elemento = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(ruta));
            bool resultado = elemento.Displayed;
            return resultado;
        }
       
    }
}
```

el resto del código para manejar el navegador funciona correctamente; y al momento de llamar el método al ejecutarse, se abre otra vez el navegador "vacío" y el método falla.
NOTA: son nuevo en C#

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer, es tener un método que me permita consultar la presencia o no de un determinado elemento, de manera de tomar una decisión (seguir o no, con la ejecución del código). El código a continuación (como esta) me abre dos instancias del navegador. Ahora pongo el código completo para ver todo el contexto.

Comment: Bienvenido. [Edita](/posts/561080/edit) la pregunta aclarando eso y sube el error que obtienes, en qué línea falla. De lo contrario solo podemos intentar adivinar cuál es el problema. ¿Probaste ejecutando el mismo código pero sin usar una configuración? (sin `ChromeOptions`)

Comment: La compilación no genera ninguna excepción; pero al ejecutar el código se produce una excepción  .NET Framework en windows. Por lo que puedo ver, al llamar el método, éste abre una nueva instancia del Chrome con una url "vacía" y al comprobar por xptah, falla y genera la excepción de .NET Framework

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el error _exacto_ que te aparecía, para que tu pregunta sea útil para los demás usuarios. Luego, acepta tu respuesta. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Al tratar de ser preciso para describir mi problema, pude ver dónde está el error: resulta que el objeto *IWebdriver* iniciaba una instancia en *main*, y yo quería llamar a mi método, pero que utilice la instancia del objeto que ya estaba abierto, entonces la invocación es:

```
var c = Presentado(driver, ruta);
            Console.WriteLine(c);
```

Y el método quedaría así:

```
static bool Presentado(IWebDriver driver, string ruta)
    {   
        var elemento = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(ruta));
        bool resultado = elemento.Displayed;
        return resultado;
    }
```